# How to use map before setting state

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change the value of the Boolean from the mock data in onClick. I am maintaining the state to hold the mock values. I need to change the Boolean value from to true to false. And then I need to set that false value in the state. When I am doing console log I can see all three items from the mock but when I am trying to select the value it's showing as undefined. I have posted the code below any one can guide me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Mock Data:

```
const custDetail = {
    customers: [
      {
        name: "Abc",
        isCreated: true,
      },
      {
        name: "bcd",
        isCreated: true,
      },
      {
        name: "Dec",
        isCreated: true,
      },
    ],
  };
```

Code:

```
const [creatingCust, setCreatingCust] = useState([custDetail])

const onHandle = () => {
const custData = [...creatingCust]
custData.map((customerData) => (
  //console.log(customerData.customers.isCreated) is giving undefined but if I removed
  //isCreated I am getting values
  customerData.customers.isCreated === false
  setState(custData)
))
```

Comment: `customers` is an array. So `customers.isCreated` should be `customers[index].isCreated`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create your customers Mock data like this:

```
const custDetail = [
  { 
    name:'Abc',
    isCreated:true
  },
  {
    name:'bcd',
    isCreated:true
  },
  {
    name:'Dec',
    isCreated:true
  }
]
```

Watch out for your quote placement. You cant begin with a `"` and end with a `'`

You dont need the part with `= { customers:[` because with this you are creating an object with one key value pair which contains an array of your objects.

Second, remove the brackets in your useState. So it should look like this:

```
const [creatingCust, setCreatingCust] = useState(custDetail)
```

If your use the brackets, you are just wrapping your data into another array.

And to answer your question. If you make these changes you can use the `.map` function to replace the value.
So you can do something like ths:

```
const changeValues = () => {
  const newData = creatingCust.map(customer => {
    return {
      ...customer,
      isCreated: false
    }
  });
  setCreatingCust(newData)
```

Comment: Good answer! Also, in fixing the mapping (to return the new data that is set), you forgot to comment on one of the largest flaws in the OP's code-- state should never be mutated (like they were doing within their original `.map` call). Instead, the correct pattern is what you have here-- immutably creating some new data (e.g., by mapping), and then setting the state to the new data, replacing the old w/o mutating it.